# Rivets.js - events unbind when model changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, rivets.js

I'm experiencing a strange issue with Rivets.js. I created the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8ua3thef/) to boil down the issue.

If you click the two buttons at the bottom in succession ("Delete outer A", and then "Delete inner 5"), everything works normally. *However*, if you perform the same action by clicking the "Delete" button next to the "outer A" text box, followed by the "Delete" button next to the "inner 5" text box, the code breaks. Inspecting the second "Delete" button after the first one is clicked reveals that the on-click event handler that was originally attached to the second "Delete" button is no longer bound. Why does the event handler "unbind itself" when the model changes?

Here's my code:

**Javascript**

```
// Create model
var myModel = [
    {
        "id" : "outer A",
        "inner" : [
            { "id" : "inner 1" },
            { "id" : "inner 2" }
        ]
    }, {
        "id" : "outer B",
        "inner" : [
            { "id" : "inner 3" },
            { "id" : "inner 4" },
            { "id" : "inner 5" }
        ]
    }
];

// Bind model to DIV using rivets
rivets.bind($('#sidebarDIV'), {myModel: myModel});

// Bind click handler: delete outer object
$('#deleteOuter_A').click(function(){
    console.log('delete outer');
    myModel.splice(0,1);
});

$('#deleteInner_5').click(function(){
    console.log('delete inner');
    myModel[0].inner.splice(2,1);
});

// Does not work
$('.deleteOuter').click(function(){
    console.log('delete outer');
    myModel.splice(0,1);
});

$('.deleteInner').click(function(){
    console.log('delete inner');
    myModel[0].inner.splice(2,1);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebarDIV">
    <div rv-each-sidebar="myModel" class="outerTab" rv-id="sidebar.id">
        <input rv-value="sidebar.id">
            <button class="deleteOuter">Delete</button>
            <div rv-each-inner="sidebar.inner" class="innerTab" rv-id="inner.id">
                <input rv-value="inner.id">
                <button class="deleteInner">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    <button id="deleteOuter_A">Delete outer A</button>
    <button id="deleteInner_5">Delete inner 5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample is odd as it seems to be working as expected.

When you click this button `#deleteOuter_A` your code has it splicing the first item out of the array. Which it does correctly.

When you click this button `#deleteInner_5` your code has it splicing the the third inner item from the first item in the array. Which it does correctly. Though, you must first spice the 0'th item from the array because that items `.inner` array does not have a third item.

When you click this button `.deleteOuter` your code has it splicing the the first item from your model. Which it does.

When you click this button `.deleteOuter` your code has it splicing the the third item from the inner array of the models first item. This will only work, when the first item in the array actually has 3 items.

Please let us know if this helps. 
I am going to close [this github issue](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/issues/516) you opened with this response.

Comment: Greg - what is confusing to me is that the two procedures should produce identical results, which *does not* happen. Procedures #1 is: click the "Delete outer A" button, then click the "Delete inner 5" button. Procedure #2 is: click the "Delete" button next to "outer A", then click the "Delete" button next to "inner 5".The second procedure fails, because after clicking the "Delete" button next to "outer A", the on-click event bound to the "Delete" button next to "inner 5" is unbound. What I am trying to figure out is *why* the event unbinds. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've created a modified fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqcxhcsb/3/) to make the issue more apparent.

Comment: This is also expected, you have bound all your listeners. The way that rivets binds iterators currently, is nearly identical to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218). This means that, if you remove the first item in the array, it actually removes the last item, then rebinds the first with the data from the second. Which is why the second remove inner button stull works, but the third does not. That third button is new and was not in the DOM on your initial jquery event registration. We are planning to implement the each binder more like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234)

Comment: My first SO answer so sorry about the mess. If you look at rivets source [here](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/blob/master/src/binders.coffee#L189) you should notice that if the length of the bound array decreases, rivets will unbind the models on the end of the array until the lengths match. Then [here](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/blob/master/src/binders.coffee#L218) rivets will iterate through and rebind the existing items.

Comment: Lastly. Rivets has a `on-*` binder which if used, will ensure that events are always subscribed to properly. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsbw1g3n/) with changes to use the `on-*` binder.

Comment: This makes sense - thanks so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm encountering a similar issue with a slightly different configuration. I've created two nearly-identical jsFiddles. [This one](https://jsfiddle.net/5dsm0euc/10/) works, while [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/suyxdetf/1/) does not. Any idea why?? This is very perplexing.